# Proving invariance of a functional under transformation

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

Suppose we have a functional of the form
$$
J(y)= \int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}} f(x,y,y')dx
$$
and a smooth transformation $X=\theta (x,y: \epsilon)$ , $Y=\psi (x,y: \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is a parameter. I have the following definition of invariance under a transformation:

**Definition.** The functional $J$ is invariant under the above transformation if, for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, in any subinterval $[a,b] \subset [x_{0},x_{1}]$ we have that
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y,y')dx= \displaystyle \int_{a_{\epsilon}}^{b_{\epsilon}} f(X,Y,Y')dX
$$
for all smooth functions $y$ defined on $[a,b]$. Here, $a_{\epsilon}=\theta (a,y(a): \epsilon)$, $b_{\epsilon}=\theta (b,y(b): \epsilon)$

Once said that, I'm interested in proving the invariance of the functional $$
J(y)=\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}} xy'^2dx
$$
under the transformation
$$
\begin{cases}
X=x+2\epsilon x \ln(x)\\
Y=(1+\epsilon)y
\end{cases}
$$

**My attempt:**

This would be easier if we could solve explicitly for $x$ in the first equation of the transformation, but, since we can't, suppose $x=\Theta (X; \epsilon)$ such inverse function exist(locally and for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small because of the inverse function theorem). On the other hand, we easily get $y=1/(1+\epsilon) Y$. Therefore,
$$
y'(x)=\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=\displaystyle \frac{Y'(X)}{(1+ \epsilon) \Theta'(X)}
$$
which implies that
$$
xy'dx= \frac{\Theta(X)}{\Theta '(X)} \frac{Y'(X)^2}{(1+\epsilon)^2}dX
$$
So, as you can see, if I could prove
$$
\frac{\Theta(X)}{(1+\epsilon)^2 \Theta '(X)}=X
$$
I'd be done, but I could not prove it, and actually, it doesn't seem true.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Of course we can also try to express $XY'(X)^2 dX$ in terms of $x$ and $y'(x)$. In this case, we get
$$
XY'(X)^2 dX= \displaystyle \frac{x+2 \epsilon x ln(x)}{1+ 2 \epsilon ln(x)+2 \epsilon} (1+ \epsilon)^2 y'(x)^2 dx 
$$
In any case, it is not clear to me how to reconcile this expressions with the definition :( .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this transformation is NOT a variational symmetry. From your computations above we have that,
$$
\displaystyle \int_{a_{\epsilon}}^{b_{\epsilon}} XY'(X)dX= \displaystyle \int_a^b xy'^2 dx + \displaystyle \int_a^b \displaystyle \frac{y'^2(x \epsilon ^2+2 \epsilon ^3 x ln(x))}{1+2 \epsilon ln(x)+2 \epsilon} dx
$$
And this definitely does not agree with the definition. On the other hand, even if we ignore this, if this transformation were a variational symmetry, because of the definition we should have that
$$
\displaystyle \frac{d}{d \epsilon} \left( \displaystyle \int_{a_{\epsilon}}^{b_{\epsilon}} f(X,Y,Y') dX  \right)=0
$$
But, in this case, this is obviously false.

**Remark:**

Althought this is not a variational symmetry, it's certainly true that the functional is infinitesimally invariant under the transformation, but it's no the same thing, check the definition in the book *Advanced Engineering Analysis* by Leonid P. Lebedev.